# Invalid syntax using regular expression in python 3.4

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am using the following expression in python 3.4 it gives *syntax error* but the same code works in python 2.7

```
block = re.compile(ur'DATA\(value\)[\S ]+\s((?:(?![^\n]+DATA\(value2\)).)*)', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

I am unsure what is the real issue in this expression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 3 has no `ur'...'` raw unicode string syntax. Use `r'...'` instead:

```
block = re.compile(
    r'DATA\(value\)[\S ]+\s((?:(?![^\n]+DATA\(value2\)).)*)',
    re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

If you need to create cross-Python compatible code, you'll have to use conditional code that'll decode the byte string produced by `r'...'` to a `unicode` object only on Python 2. A module like [`six`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) can help with that:

```
from six import u

block = re.compile(
    u(r'DATA\(value\)[\S ]+\s((?:(?![^\n]+DATA\(value2\)).)*)'),
    re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

Or you can create your own compatibility layer; for local one-off tests, you could see if there is a `str.decode()` method present:

```
_block_pattern = r'DATA\(value\)[\S ]+\s((?:(?![^\n]+DATA\(value2\)).)*)'
if hasattr(_block_pattern, 'decode'):
    # Python 2, decode to unicode first
    _block_pattern = _block_pattern.decode('ascii')
block = re.compile(_block_pattern, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```